# How To ADD Firefox Default Applications

Tags: linux, firefox, default, file-extension

So I'm trying to find a way to add default file extensions options to Firefox. Since for whatever reason it doesn't give you the option?

Example: Settings > General > Applications

I want to add new content types and then be able to select my default application of choice.

The current issue is, that I use an MSP client that when necessary allows us to remote into a client's workstation for troubleshooting. Normally one would just click on the "Start Remote Session," button, and it brings up the application to do so. However, since it operates in some form of Javascript (I think....?), it doesn't technically download a file for me to save and then execute through the app. It just opens the app automatically. It never gives me the option to save the a file or anything like that, that it would use for the Remote Session app.

So I want to figure out how to bypass this issue by just adding the extension needed for this process in Firefox's default content types.

Works on Windows, I'm currently on Linux. (So please don't tell me to not use linux or any form there of. That or to use wine or playonlinux. I already am)